# Pandas calculating over duplicated entries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

This is my sample dataframe

```
Price   DateOfTrasfer   PAON    Street
115000  2018-07-13 00:00    4   THE LANE
24000   2018-04-10 00:00    20  WOODS TERRACE
56000   2018-06-22 00:00    6   HEILD CLOSE
220000  2018-05-25 00:00    25  BECKWITH CLOSE
58000   2018-05-09 00:00    23  AINTREE DRIVE
115000  2018-06-21 00:00    4   EDEN VALE MEWS
82000   2018-06-01 00:00    24  ARKLESS GROVE
93000   2018-07-06 00:00    14  HORTON CRESCENT
42500   2018-06-27 00:00    18  CATHERINE TERRACE
172000  2018-05-25 00:00    67  HOLLY CRESCENT
```

this is the task to perform:

For any address that appears more than once in a dataset, define a holding period as the time
between any two consecutive transactions involving that property (i.e. N(holding_periods)
= N(appearances) - 1. Implement a function that takes price paid data and returns the
average length of a holding period and the annualised change in value between the purchase
and sale, grouped by the year a holding period ends and the property type.

```
def holding_time(df):

  df = df.copy()
  # to work only with dates (day)
  df.DateOfTrasfer = pd.to_datetime(df.DateOfTrasfer)
  
  cols = ['PAON', 'Street']
  df['address'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
  df.drop(["PAON", 'Street'],axis=1,inplace=True)

  df = df.groupby(['address', 'Price'],as_index=False).agg({'PPD':'size'})\
  .rename(columns={'PPD':'count_2'})

  return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script creates columns containing the individual holding times, the average holding time for that property, and the price changes during the holding times:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# assume df is defined above ...

hdf = df.groupby("Street", sort=False).apply(lambda c: c.values[:,1]).reset_index(name='hgb')
pdf = df.groupby("Street", sort=False).apply(lambda c: c.values[:,0]).reset_index(name='pgb')

df['holding_periods'] = hdf['hgb'].apply(lambda c: np.diff(c.astype(np.datetime64)))
df['price_changes']   = pdf['pgb'].apply(lambda c: np.diff(c.astype(np.int64)))

df['holding_periods'] = df['holding_periods'].fillna("").apply(list)
df['avg_hold'] = df['holding_periods'].apply(lambda c: np.array(c).astype(np.float64).mean() if c else 0).fillna(0)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Street','avg_hold'], keep=False, inplace=True)
```

I created 2 new dummy entries for "*Heild Close*" to test it:

```
# Input:
     Price DateOfTransfer PAON             Street
0   115000     2018-07-13    4           THE LANE
1    24000     2018-04-10   20      WOODS TERRACE
2    56000     2018-06-22    6        HEILD CLOSE
3   220000     2018-05-25   25     BECKWITH CLOSE
4    58000     2018-05-09   23      AINTREE DRIVE
5   115000     2018-06-21    4     EDEN VALE MEWS
6    82000     2018-06-01   24      ARKLESS GROVE
7    93000     2018-07-06   14    HORTON CRESCENT
8    42500     2018-06-27   18  CATHERINE TERRACE
9   172000     2018-05-25   67     HOLLY CRESCENT
10   59000     2018-06-27   12        HEILD CLOSE
11  191000     2018-07-13    1        HEILD CLOSE


# Output:

    Price DateOfTransfer PAON             Street    holding_periods   price_changes  avg_hold
0  115000     2018-07-13    4           THE LANE                 []              []       0.0
1   24000     2018-04-10   20      WOODS TERRACE                 []              []       0.0
2   56000     2018-06-22    6        HEILD CLOSE  [5 days, 16 days]  [3000, 132000]      10.5
3  220000     2018-05-25   25     BECKWITH CLOSE                 []              []       0.0
4   58000     2018-05-09   23      AINTREE DRIVE                 []              []       0.0
5  115000     2018-06-21    4     EDEN VALE MEWS                 []              []       0.0
6   82000     2018-06-01   24      ARKLESS GROVE                 []              []       0.0
7   93000     2018-07-06   14    HORTON CRESCENT                 []              []       0.0
8   42500     2018-06-27   18  CATHERINE TERRACE                 []              []       0.0
9  172000     2018-05-25   67     HOLLY CRESCENT                 []              []       0.0
```

Your question also mentions *the annualised change in value between the purchase and sale, grouped by the year a holding period ends and the property type*, but there is no property type column (PAON maybe?) and grouping by year would make the table extremely difficult to read, so I did not implement it. As it stands, you have the holding time between each transaction and the change of price at each time, so it should be trivial to implement a function to use this information to plot annualized data, if you so choose.

Comment: I forgot to add that column, I will test your script in the extended df

Comment: I had to change

this line 
* df['holding_periods'] = hdf['hgb'].apply(lambda c: np.diff(c.astype(np.datetime64)))
to this
* df['holding_periods'] = hdf['hgb'].apply(lambda c: np.diff(c.astype('datetime64[D]')))

even if it was printing out the holding time in minutes

Comment: i get negative values

Prop_Type address holding_periods price_changes avg_hold
1 F REVIVAL COURT HALF MOON LANE [-190 days, -398 days, -289 days, -5 days, 25 ... [-56000, 161000, -60000, -85000, 150000, -5000... -52.50

Comment: Yes, because the price must have dropped between holding periods - that's the default behavior of ```np.diff()```, which is what I used. If you don't want that, just take the ```abs``` of the output of diff before saving it in your DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i also noticed that I had to sort the list of files, which has fixed the avg-price. But i guess that the holding_periods now should be always positive, am i wrong?

Comment: @fabio.geraci if they're passed in the correct order, then yes, theoretically they should be. It's always possible to have bad/wrong data entries, however.

Comment: how can implement and rise an error with the two dates that return a negative difference?

Answer (score 0):

After manually calculating the max and min average difference checking, I had to modify the accepted solution, in order to match the manual results.

these are the database, this function is a bit slow so I would appreciate a faster implementation.

```
urls = ['http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-2020.csv',
        'http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-2019.csv',
        'http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-2018.csv']


def holding_time(df):
    df = df.copy()

    df = df[['Price', 'DateOfTrasfer', 'Prop_Type', 'Postcode', 'PAON', 'Street']]

    df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Postcode', 'PAON', 'Street'], keep=False)]

    cols = ['Postcode', 'PAON', 'Street']
    df['address'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)

    df['address'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))

    df.DateOfTrasfer = pd.to_datetime(df.DateOfTrasfer)

    df['avg_price'] = df.groupby(['address'])['Price'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().mean())
    df['avg_hold'] = df.groupby(['address'])['DateOfTrasfer'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.mean())

    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['address'], keep='first', inplace=True)

    df.drop(['Price', 'DateOfTrasfer', 'address'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = df.dropna()

    df['avg_hold'] = df['avg_hold'].map('Days {:.1f}'.format)
    df['avg_price'] = df['avg_price'].map('£{:,.1F}'.format)

    return df
```